# Why is my jquery removing the first elements in a list instead of specified ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to loop over a list in my html with a .each() loop, and removing any elements with matching ids.

```
<ul>
<li id="0" class="liRem">zero</li>
<li id="1" class="liRem">one</li>
<li id="2" class="liRem">two</li>
<li id="3" class="liRem">three </li>
<li id="4" class="liRem">four </li></ul>
```

And the jquery:

```
var output = [1, 3];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li").each(function () {
        if(this.id in output) {
            $(this).remove();
        };
    });
});
```

However, instead of removing the specified li element, it just removes the next 'first' one on the page.

Also, I can't change the fact that I'm using an array, and the list is the only one on the html document. I'm new to jquery, so any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't have the functionality "value in array". This is used for for loops to loop over each element of an object.

Instead you should use either JQuerys [inArray method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or array.indexOf(value) > -1.
Additionally the Ids are strings, while your array contains numbers.

This works:

```
var output = ["1", "3"];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li").each(function () {
        if(output.indexOf(this.id) > -1) {
            $(this).remove();
        };
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/07atsh5o/

Answer (score 1):

try this script using jquery [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) and get the id using jquery .attr('id')

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var output = ["1", "3"];
                $("ul li").each(function () {
                      if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), output) !== -1){   

                        $(this).remove();
                    };
                });
            });    
</script>
```

Comment: you should probably use the same identifier for jQuery, not jQuery and $.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad JavaScript doesn't have a nice function to simply check if an array contains a certain element. Nevertheless you could make one yourself by using this snippet:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function (search) {
   for (key in this) {
       if (this[key] == search) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This function wil check whether your array will contain the given value or not and returns `true` or `false`. You can use it like so:

```
output.contains($(this).attr('id'));
```

Please also note my usage of retrieving an id of an element, because the way you do it now is incorrect. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fobhb6hr/) for you, so you can check it out yourself and play with it a bit.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The "in" function doesn't work for the array, since "in" is to be used with for loop, because it gives only index values.

So try using one simple for loop with it:
And here is the example demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/HimeshS/pqrtqtkv/1/

```
for(var i in output){
               if(this.id == output[i]) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
           }
```